# Analysis of multi-vectors

Tags: vector-analysis, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

Let $v:=u+x\sigma_x+y\sigma_y+z\sigma_z$ be a multi-vector.

---

How does one take the derivate with respect to x?

$$
\frac{dv}{dx} = \sigma_x
$$

1. correct?

---

How does one take the total derivative?

$$
dv=du+\sigma_xdx+\sigma_ydy + \sigma_zdz
$$

2. correct?

---

How does one take the integral with respect to dx?
$$
\int v dx = \int udx+ \int x\sigma_xdx+\int y\sigma_ydx+ \int z\sigma_zdx\\
=ux+\frac{1}{2}x^2\sigma_x+yx\sigma_y+zx\sigma_z+c
$$

3. correct?

---

How does one take the integral over the volume of the multi-vector?
$$
V=\int (u+x\sigma_x+y\sigma_y+z\sigma_z)(\sigma_x \sigma_y \sigma_z)dxdydz\\
=\int (u\sigma_x \sigma_y \sigma_z+x\sigma_x\sigma_x \sigma_y \sigma_z+y\sigma_y\sigma_x \sigma_y \sigma_z+z\sigma_z\sigma_x \sigma_y \sigma_z)dxdydz\\
=\int (u\sigma_x \sigma_y \sigma_z+x \sigma_y \sigma_z-y\sigma_x \sigma_z+z\sigma_x \sigma_y)dxdydz\\
=uxyz\sigma_x \sigma_y \sigma_z+x \sigma_y \sigma_z-y\sigma_x \sigma_z+z\sigma_x \sigma_y+c\\
=uxyz\sigma_x \sigma_y \sigma_z+x \sigma_y \sigma_z+y\sigma_z \sigma_x+z\sigma_x \sigma_y+c
$$

4. correct?

The last one has me confused. I do not understand why the volume depends on the area terms $x \sigma_y \sigma_z+y\sigma_z \sigma_x+z\sigma_x \sigma_y$ and on a scalar $c$ and pseudoscalar $uxyz\sigma_x \sigma_y \sigma_z$.  Why is the volume not a scalar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are all correct.  For the last, you are free to use a scalar volume element, should you choose.

There are however, some circumstances where you'd want a trivector volume element as you have done.  In particular, the expression of the fundamental theorem of calculus for volume integrals can be naturally expressed using a trivector volume element.

That theorem, for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, stated roughly, is:

Given mulitvector functions $ F, G$, a trivector valued volume element $ d^3 \mathbf{x} = d\mathbf{x}_1 \wedge d\mathbf{x}_2 \wedge d\mathbf{x}_3 = du dv dw\, \mathbf{x}_u \wedge \mathbf{x}_v \wedge \mathbf{x}_w $, where $\mathbf{x}_a = \partial \mathbf{x}/\partial a$, one has:

$$\int_V F d^3\mathbf{x} \stackrel{ \leftrightarrow }{\boldsymbol{\nabla}} G= \int_{\partial V} F d^2 \mathbf{x} G,$$
where $
\stackrel{ \leftrightarrow }{\boldsymbol{\nabla}}$ acts bidirectionally on $F,G$, and
$ \partial V $ is the boundary of the volume $ V $, and the surface integral 
over the $ d^2 \mathbf{x} $ bivector area element has a counterclockwise orientation.

Spelled out more explicitly, that surface integral has the form

$$\begin{aligned}\int_{\partial V} F d^2 \mathbf{x} G&=\int {\left.{{\left( {F d\mathbf{x}_1 \wedge d\mathbf{x}_2 G} \right)}}\right\vert}_{{\Delta w}} \\ &\qquad +\int {\left.{{\left( {F d\mathbf{x}_2 \wedge d\mathbf{x}_3 G} \right)}}\right\vert}_{{\Delta u}} \\ &\qquad +\int {\left.{{\left( {F d\mathbf{x}_3 \wedge d\mathbf{x}_1 G} \right)}}\right\vert}_{{\Delta v}}.\end{aligned}$$

The statics solution of Maxwell's equation is a nice physical example of an 
an oriented multivector integral.  Given a multivector electromagnitic field 
$$   F = \mathbf{E} + I c \mathbf{B},$$
and a multivector current
$$J = \frac{1}{{\epsilon}} \left( { \rho - \frac{1}{{c}} \mathbf{J} } \right),$$
the enclosed multivector current is related to the field by
$$\int_{\partial V} d^2\, \mathbf{x} F = \int_V d^3 \mathbf{x} \, J.$$

Of course, you can express this using scalar integrals too
$$\int_{\partial V} dA\, \hat{\mathbf{n}} F = \int_V dV\, J,$$
where the normal is related to the surface area element by the unit pseudoscalar using $d^2\, \mathbf{x} = dA I \hat{\mathbf{n}} $, and where the volume element satisfies $d^3 \, \mathbf{x} = I dV$.

Both of these multivector integral variations pack a lot of information, as they can be decomposed into scalar, vector, bivector and trivector grades, and yield the conventional "enclosed current relations":

$$\begin{aligned}\int_{\partial V} dA\, \hat{\mathbf{n}} \cdot \mathbf{D}        &=  \int_V dV\, \rho \\ \int_{\partial V} dA\, \hat{\mathbf{n}} \times \mathbf{H}       &=  \int_V dV\, \mathbf{J} \\ \int_{\partial V} dA\, \hat{\mathbf{n}} \times \mathbf{E}       &= 0 \\ \int_{\partial V} dA\, \hat{\mathbf{n}} \cdot \mathbf{B}        &= 0.\end{aligned}$$

Comment: So, I can use $\int\int\int \mathbf{u} dxdydz=\mathbf{V}$ as a "scalar integration", or I can use $\int\int\int \mathbf{u} \sigma_x\sigma_y\sigma_z dxdydz$ as a "trivector integration". To help me understand the difference, can you provide a simple physical example of each?

Comment: Added a physical example (of both, since they are related by duality) from electromagnetism.

Comment: ..., and then showed how the single equation in multivector form is related to the conventional relationships.

Comment: Hello, when you pose the relation $d^2\mathbf{x}=dA I \mathbf{\hat{n}}$, we actually write the integral as $\int_{\partial V}dA \mathbf{\hat{n}} F$. How did you eliminate the term $I$? Also, does the relation $d^3\mathbf{x}=dV$ hold?

Comment: edited the answer.

Comment: That is very interesting. For instance, if I start with $V=\int_M d^3 \mathbf{x}=I\int_M dV$. Since the unit pseudoscalar is the imaginary term, the two notations are related by $i$?

Comment: Careful with your notation.  Your $V$ is a pseudoscalar (trivector), but your $dV$ is a scalar.  But yes, any trivector in $R^3$ is a scalar multiple of the unit pseudoscalar $I = \sigma_x \sigma_y \sigma_z$.

Comment: Can I kindly ask you to take a look at my other relation question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3336190/volume-integral-zoo-geometric-calculus-riemannian-volumes-lagrangian-densitie A bunch of people of there are in desperate need of an answer.

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay I was able to provide a partial answer to that question.